# Define element.style in shopify .liquid theme code

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

Jquery slideshow not working.

I tried to override the "default" container width in the "NEW STANDARD" shopify theme. the default MAX width was 884 px. My client wanted to expand the entire site width to 948px, including the slides of course. I guess in the midst of doing this, I changed something that disabled the functionality of the slideshow.

I have compared the original theme files to my edited theme files in textwrangler to try and see if there was some little detail that was making it not work. But after analyzing the JSHOP.js file, the style.css.liquid file, the theme.liquid file and so on, I was NOT able to find the issue.

it seems that the element.style is not defined for the #SLIDE div. The CSS seems just fine. but inorder for the left-margin to recalculate for each slide (i.e. 948*2*-1, 948*3*-1), there must javascript in the JSHOP source code (aka element.style). right?

the #slideshow-controls are not showing up underneath the slideshow.

the slideshow doesn't show more than one slide

To see the website -- here are the details:
website: www.deekeller.com 
password: pink: 1111

Comment: there doesnt seem to be any problem. the slideshow has more than one slide and the slide show controls are also there.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned. @Brighton did you solve this problem? Judging by the launched site you have, could you post how you solved it as an answer?

Comment: @ChrisMoschini Hey chris! So sorry about that - I actually cannot even remember what the issue was. I think I just found another way to do it because I couldn't figure it out. I'll "close" the question - how do i do that?